# Rails 5 - CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to know if CanCan gem (or cancancan) works fine with rails 5. On http://www.ready4rails.net/gems/cancan, it is flaged as "unknown"... I'm about to start a new project and it's really relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem by the Ryan it is not supported anymore. You should use [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#mission) it is already support [Rails 5](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/pull/289)

Answer (score 4):

CanCan was abandoned a couple of years ago. You'll want to use [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), which is the continuation of CanCan.

Although the documentation hasn't been updated to reflect the latest changes in Rails, you can see from the check-in comments that work has been done to address Rails 5.